# Error initializing shared pointer with an array of list<int>

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm trying to implement a Graph class with shared_ptr.  I've declared my class as below.

```
class Graph
{
    public:
        Graph(int V);
        Graph()=delete;
        void AddEdge(int src, int dest);
        void BFS(int s);
        ~Graph();
    private:
        int V;
        std::shared_ptr<std::list<int>[]> adj;
};
```

When I try to initialize my adjList like below in the constructor, I'm getting a compilation error.

```
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = std::make_shared<std::list<int>[]>(new std::list<int>[V]);
}
```

Error:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:717:39:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::__cxx11::list<int> []; _Args = {std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> >*}]’
Graph.cpp:21:67:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:145:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::list<int>::list(std::__cxx11::list<int>*)’
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Rethink your approach. Why to you want a `std::shared_ptr` to an array of `std::list`? Consider using a `std::vector` of `std::list`s as a replacement.

Comment: C++11 has only one `make_shared` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 has only one [`make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) function. This is what its prototype looks like:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

1. `T` can't be an array.
2. The function accepts arguments that will be passed to the `T` constructor, but `std::list` has no constructor that can accept `new std::list<int>[V]`.